# Ubuntu 20.04 grub-install /dev/sda installation failed in hp elitebook

Tags: grub2, hp, ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-mate, grub-efi

I have tried numerous method but all of them failed every time and I land on grub console. Why Ubuntu has this issue as I never face this issue with other distros

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? What model HP? Have you updated UEFI to latest available from HP for your system? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Often issue is that you do not have correct partition on drive for grub to install into. If UEFI install you need ESP and if BIOS on gpt you need bios_grub. But if dual booting need same type

Comment: I tried UEFI to install, ho elitebook 8470p

Comment: Mostly it's stuck at grub bootloader. By YouTube tutorial I able to boot in is but than whenever I restart I have to encounter same issue for grub screen wait for commsnds

Comment: Typical HP. One time boot works. Some have said HP UEFI update helps. Some just live with booting from UEFI, some use rEFInd which seems to work as it really is using UEFI's fallback or hard drive boot entry which grub also now creates. (Do you have UEFI drive boot entry?) `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see details on entries.  Some other work arounds, depending on whether dual booting or more than one drive, some are better than others: Sony, HP & others workarounds:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win